# I have a problem with gesture recognizers responding to incorrect subviews, what gives?

Tags: iphone, ipad, event-handling, subview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a parent view called ImageViewController. To this view I add up to two subviews called ImageDetailViewController. In this detail view controller I declare a few gestures that need to do certain things on **their respective views only**. Here is the code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeModeButtonPushed:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tap setDelegate:self];
[openGLView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchDidDrag:)];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[openGLView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[panRecognizer release];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *shiftRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(shiftView:)];
[shiftRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
[openGLView addGestureRecognizer:shiftRecognizer];
[shiftRecognizer release];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecog = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewPinched:)];
[openGLView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecog];
[pinchRecog release];
```

So I need to have two of these detail views load up next to each other inside of this parent view, and then I need to be able to do these gestures on one view or the other, and have that view respond.

**The problem** is that when I 1 finger pan around with 1 finger, sometimes it will call on the view it is supposed to, but most often, it fires on the other view! It doesn't make any sense! I have tried debugging and everything else I can think of, but I just can't see how two separately declared objects can get mixed up like this.

To make things stranger, there are some gestures that **do** work correctly. So it's only this one finger pan around gesture that screws everything up.

What could I be missing? How can I even debug this? Everything is looking like the objects are indeed separate, but they just aren't behaving that way...

Comment: What are these detail views like?

Answer (score 0):

You could debug/solve this by finding out what view your gesture recogniser is calling on: Have a look at this code:

(void)NAMEOFFUNCTION:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

```
if ([yourViewController.view pointInside:[recognizer locationInView:presentationSlideViewController.view] withEvent:nil]) {


}
```

filter through all your subviews, in this example i'm checking to see if the finger touch is below a defined x and then y coordinate. First check to see if the point is inside the _buttonVIew subview://

```
if ([_buttonView pointInside:[recognizer locationInView:_buttonView] withEvent:nil]) {
```

Then check to see if the touch is in a coordinate lower than 50

```
    if (([recognizer locationInView:_buttonView].x < 50) && ([_leftArrow isEnabled])) {
        pageIndex -= 1;
    }
   //otheriwse check to see if its over 970
        else if (([recognizer locationInView:_buttonView].x > 970) && ([_rightArrow isEnabled])) {
            pageIndex += 1;
        }

    [self scrollViewScrollToRect:pageIndex];
    [self fadeArrows:1.0];
    return;

    }
```

}